# Looking for improvement of slide down animation with angular.js

Tags: css, html, angularjs, css-animations

I do have a running code sample (http://jsfiddle.net/Fuunq/) which shows a slide down animation using angular.js (1.2.0). But there are two issues that I don't know how to solve:

a) When clicking on the 'Add item' link, the animation first moves down the 'Add item' link and then slides in the new item from the top. How can this be changed, that the 'Add item' link slides down together with the new appearing item?

b) How can I prevent that the items do fade in when the page gets loaded for the first time?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">    
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="animation-slide-down">
        <div class="item">
            <div>Name: {{item.name}}</div>
            <div>Color: {{item.color}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#" ng-click="addItem()">Add item</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #34ac54;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide_down {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -100;
  }

  99% {
    z-index: -100;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slide_down {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -100;
  }

  99% {
    z-index: -100;
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}

.animation-slide-down.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: slide_down 3s ease-in;
  animation: slide_down 4s ease-in;
}
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'foo';

    $scope.items = [
        {name: 'Item 1', color: 'blue'},
        {name: 'Item 2', color: 'red'}
    ]

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        $scope.items.push({name: 'Another item', color: 'black'})
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

a) as far as i know this can only be achieved with a negative margin-top transitions to your target value 5px. There is one problem with this: you have to know the exact height of one item.

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide_down {
  0% {
    margin-top: -68px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -100;
  }

  99% {
    z-index: -100;
  }

  100% {
      margin-top:5px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

b) you can use the $animate service. The service has an enabled method, so you may disable or enable the animations at any time. here is your controller code that disables the animation on start and after the start enables the animation. the trick is the $timeout service. with that you defer activating the animations until the next digest cycle happens:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $animate, $timeout) {
    $animate.enabled(false);

    $scope.name = 'foo';

    $scope.items = [
        {name: 'Item 1', color: 'blue'},
        {name: 'Item 2', color: 'red'}
    ]

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        $scope.items.push({name: 'Another item', color: 'black'})
    }
    $timeout(function(){
     $animate.enabled(true);
    });
}
```

here is the working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/CKF47/